# Confidence Interval (CI) simulation in R: How?

Tags: r, random, statistics, sampling, confidence-interval

I was wondering how I could check via simulation in R that the 95% Confidence Interval obtained from a binomial test with 5 successes in 15 trials when ***TRUE p = .5*** has a 95% "Coverage Probability" in the long-run?

Here is the 95% CI for such a test using R (how can show that the following CI has a 95% coverage in the long-run if *TRUE p = .5*):

```
as.numeric(binom.test(x = 5, n = 15, p = .5)[[4]])
# > [1] 0.1182411 0.6161963 (in the long-run 95% of the time, ".5" is contained within these
#                            two numbers, how to show this in R?)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but there are several formulas for the binomial proportion's CI. Which one do you want to use?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, does that now sound clearer what I want to achieve?

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I guess your comments seem irrelavant to OP's question! OP just wants to know the coverage probability of the current method for CI in R in the long-run. Please delete your comments!

Comment: FWIW, binom.test uses Clopper-Pearson intervals, which overcover: see [this figure](http://imgur.com/a/N1Ff5) from Agresti's *Categorical Analysis* book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
fun <- function(n = 15, p = 0.5){
    x <- rbinom(1, size = n, prob = p)
    res <- binom.test(x, n, p)[[4]]
    c(Lower = res[1], Upper = res[2])
}

set.seed(3183)
R <- 10000
sim <- t(replicate(R, fun()))
```

Note that `binom.test` when called with 5 successes, 15 trials and p = 0.5 will always return the same value, hence the call to `rbinom`. The number of successes will vary. We can compute the proportion of cases when `p` is between `Lower` and `Upper`.

```
cov <- mean(sim[,1] <= .5 & .5 <= sim[,2])
```

Comment: It gives `0.9654`. At least with that value of `set.seed`.

Comment: I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579541/simulation-for-confidence-interval-in-r) you can help?