# Simulation for Confidence interval in R

Tags: r, random, statistics, sampling, confidence-interval

I have an R function that provides the 95% confidence Interval for the *ncp* (non-centrality parameter) of a t distribution.

Via simulation in R, is it possible to show that in the long-run the CIs from this R function capture a given *TRUE ncp* (here "2" same as input *t*) 95%  of the time?

(I appreciate any ideas as to how to do this)

```
CI.ncp <- function(t, N){

  f <- function (ncp, alpha, q, df) {  
abs(suppressWarnings(pt(q = t, df = N - 1, ncp, lower.tail = FALSE)) - alpha) }

sapply(c(0.025, 0.975),
function(x) optim(1, f, alpha = x, q = t, df = N - 1, control = list(reltol = (.Machine$double.eps)))[[1]]) }

#Example of Use:
CI.ncp(t = 2, N = 20) # gives: -0.08293755  4.03548862 

#(in the long-run 95% of the time, "2" is contained within these
# two numbers, how to show this in R?)
```

Here is what I have tried with no success:

```
fun <- function(t = 2, N = 20){

  ncp = rt(1, N - 1, t)
  CI.ncp(t = 2, N = 20)
  mean(ncp <= 2 & 2 <= ncp )
   }

 R <- 1000
 sim <- t(replicate(R, fun()))
 coverage <- mean(sim[,1] <= 2 & 2 <= sim[,2])
```

Comment: have you made an attempt to apply the logic of the answer to [your other very closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572226/confidence-interval-ci-simulation-in-r-how) to this problem? If so, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the that we need to feed the random `ncp` obtained from the `fun` in the `CI.ncp`:

```
 fun <- function(t = 2, N = 20){ ;

   ncp = rt(1, N - 1, t);
   CI.ncp(t = ncp, N = 20);
   }

  R <- 1e4 ;
  sim <- t(replicate(R, fun()));
  coverage <- mean(sim[,1] <= 2 & 2 <= sim[,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use package `MBESS`.

```
#install.packages("MBESS")
library(MBESS)

fun <- function(t = 2, N = 20, alpha = 0.95){
   x = rt(1, N - 1, t)
   conf.limits.nct(x, df = N, conf.level = alpha)[c(1, 3)]
}

set.seed(5221)
R <- 1000
sim <- t(replicate(R, fun()))
head(sim)
coverage <- mean(sim[,1] <= 2 & 2 <= sim[,2])
coverage
[1] 0.941
```

Comment: @rnorouzian Yes and no. No because there's a bug in `c(.025, .0975)`, it should be `.975`. (an extra zero.) Otherwise yes.

Comment: Maybe we can test that this way: `fun <- function(t = 2, N = 20, alpha = 0.95){;
  x = rt(1, N - 1, t);
  c(conf.limits.nct(x, df = N, conf.level = alpha)[c(1, 3)], x);
};

sim <- t(replicate(1e3, fun()));
coverage <- mean(sim[,1] <= 2 & 2 <= sim[,2]);

CI = qt(c(.025, .975), 19, 2);

mean(CI[1] <= sim[, 3] & sim[, 3] <= CI[2])`

Comment: @rnorouzian Sounds good. I've just tested it and the results of both methods were consistent with one another.